# Default Namespace created when append the XML document

Tags: c#, xml

I was trying to append the xml file in the existing file, everything works fine but I have an issue with default namespace when it appends.

This is the code I use to append:

```
 XmlNode newChild = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "image", "");
    newChild.Attributes.Append(doc.CreateAttribute("name", filename));

    XmlNode xmlElement = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "width", null);
    xmlElement.InnerText = widthValue[1].TrimStart();
    newChild.AppendChild(xmlElement);
```

am getting an output like below

```
<image d2p1:name="" xmlns:d2p1="test.jpg">
    <width>1024</width>
</image>
```

but I was trying to append like:

```
<image name="test.jpg">
    <width>1024</width>
</image>
```

Comment: BTW, the output you're getting does contain a namespace, but not default namespace. That would be something like `xmlns="something"` and it doesn't affect attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others suggested, using LINQ to XML might be easier in general.

But if you want to stick with using `XmlDocument`, to fix the issue, change your code to the following:

```
var attribute = doc.CreateAttribute("name");
attribute.Value = filename;
newChild.Attributes.Append(attribute);
```

The problem with the code you have is that [`doc.CreateAttribute("foo", "bar")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtyc931d.aspx) creates an attribute with the name `foo` in a namespace with the URI `bar`. That's really not what you want.

Comment: ,thanks a lot for the explain and the code too.I will use Linq from next time onward (it looks pretty straight forward). thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're able to use it but you can do it with Linq To Xml as follows:

```
// NOTE: Requires `using System.Xml.Linq;`
var newChild = new XElement("image");
newChild.Add(new XAttribute("name", filename));
doc.Add(newChild);

XElement xmlElement = new XElement("width");
xmlElement.Value = widthValue[1].TrimStart();
newChild.Add(xmlElement);
```

Comment: ,thanks a lot for your help,am halfway thru using xml,is this anyway i can remove the default namespace

Comment: Unless you want to remove it in post processing of the XML, I don't know how.

Comment: @Usher - I'd probably go as far as to say that I don't think it is possible with `System.Xml.XmlDocument` alone (sticking my neck out a bit based on what I've seen). If you're trying to manipulate *XML-like* data that isn't truly XML then I'd suggest using a parser specific to whatever format it is.

Comment: thanks again for your comment,let me take a day and get advice from other experts,nothing gonna help then i will start using Linq.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use LINQ to XML to manipulate the file?

```
var xml = XDocument.Parse(@"<xml><image name=""first_image.jpg""><width>800</width></image></xml>");
xml.Root.Add(new XElement("image", new XAttribute("name", "test.jpg"), new XElement("width", "1024")));
var result = xml.ToString();
```

The code above produces the following result:

```
<xml>
  <image name="first_image.jpg">
    <width>800</width>
  </image>
  <image name="test.jpg">
    <width>1024</width>
  </image>
</xml>
```

No unwanted namespace information.

Comment: thanks a lot, i haven't think about Linq when i was startin.Look like Linq is the best way to deal with it.

Comment: already i have an xml file,this part is only append to the existing xml file.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea of the example. The first line produces a xml object (you can replace it with you code to load the contents from a file). The rest just add another node at the root node. Hope this helps you.